# How to strip attachments from inbound mails in Mailgun before POSTing?

Tags: mailgun

Is it possible for Mailgun to POST only the non-attachment part of emails to my API, to prevent big attachments affecting the performance of the app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mailgun can host the attachments for you with the inbound functionality.

You can use the Events API command `store(notify=”http://myapp/post”)` specifying as shown the notify option, which will send a webhook to your application with a URL on message arrival.

One of the headers sent with through webhook will look something like: `["[{\"url\": \"https://api.mailgun.net/v2/domains/YOURDOMAIN/messages/ALARGESTRINGOFCHARACTERS/attachments/0\", \"content-type\": \"META/META\", \"name\": \"MYFILE.EXT\", \"size\": 74622}]"]`

Then you can retrieve it and delete the stored message. 
Keep in mind that stored messages are kept only for so long so you should process attachments rapidly.

This is one of the options of the routes functionality that Mailgun gives you.
Personally I love it ! Let me know if something is unclear i can dig into more details!
Best,

Comment: How can u acctually dowload the file to your own server?

Comment: @Brainmaniac check this link, it may help: https://www.mailgun.com/blog/handle-incoming-emails-like-a-pro-mailgun-api-2-0

Comment: This worked for me, Thank you API_sherriff_orlie and Max MacLeod

Comment: @Antuan Thanks! thats good. Figured it out though (for laravel peeps): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46089492/mailgun-inbound-email-attachment-save-to-laravel-storage/52178564#52178564

Answer (score 1):

I am getting mail on the Mailgun which I am routing to my local server and their. I am parsing the JSON but problem is coming in case of attachments. In attachment json, it is showing the path of temporary file on mailgun server. I need to download the attachment and store it on my local machine.
My question is how to retrieve that attachment. Do we have any API for that?

Comment: I have the same question. Where you able to resolve this?

Answer (score -1):

To access the data from the link, you will need to specify credentials as your get parameters. The user is 'api' and the password is your mailgun's private key

Please refer to this answer that I've given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43872301/mailgun-incoming-mail-event-fetch-attachment-url/47170449#47170449)