# Can't receive email with attachment from mailgun

Tags: node.js, express, mailgun

I create router from mailgun to forward emails to my website endpoint [www.example.com/messages](http://www.example.com/messages)
and I received emails successfully when it only text but when i attach file to this email, I don't receive any thing and the request body is empty

```
export const incomingEmails = async (req, res) => {

const from = req.body.from.split('<')[0].trim();
const sender = req.body.sender;
const recipient = req.body.recipient;
const subject = req.body.subject;
const html = req.body['stripped-html'];

try {
    const incomingEmail = new Support({
        from,
        sender,
        recipient,
        subject,
        html
    })

    await incomingEmail.save();
    res.sendStatus(200)
} catch (error) {
    res.status(500)
    next(new Error('something went wrong'))
}}
```

i'm using url encoded middle ware

```
app.use(express.urlencoded())
```

**note the stack I use is node and express at at backend**

Comment: show your codes on how you send the email so we can debug.

Comment: i update the question with my code

Comment: where is the part you mention about file

Comment: this endpoint will receive email coming from mailgun, my question how can i tweak it so i can receive emails with attachments, because until now this endpoint receive only emails with text content

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mailgun incoming mail event fetch attachment url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43872301/mailgun-incoming-mail-event-fetch-attachment-url)

Comment: my main problem is the request body is empty when i receive emails with attachment but when emails with only text content, i can see the body and extract my information from it, so it could be something missing in my code (middleware for example or some modification need to be add in my endpoint)

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue and I figured out why. I used the **forward method** to receive emails on my backend. The forward method only works when there is no attachment. With attachments, Mailgun will return an empty body because Mailgun has to first store the attachments, which is asynchronous.

In order to solve this issue, you have to use the **store method** instead of the forward method:

> store(notification endpoint)
>
> Stores the message temporarily (for up to 3 days) on Mailgun’s servers
> so that you can retrieve it later. This is helpful for large
> attachments that may cause time-outs or if you just want to retrieve
> them later to reduce the frequency of hits on your server.

You have to edit your route in the Mailgun web app: go under "Receiving" in the menu and then edit your existing route.

Instead of entering:

```
forward("http://example.com/callback")
```

You enter:

```
store(notify="http://example.com/callback")
```