# Mailgun - Inbound email attachment save to laravel storage

Tags: php, laravel, mailgun

When the request of an inbound email is parsed by the controller, the attachments are a json blob array of the form below.

```
"attachments": [
    {
        "url": "https://se.api.mailgun.net/v3/domains/mg.example.com/messages/eyJwIjpmYWxzZSwiayI6IjBhYjM5MWE5LTU5YzUtNGJkMS1hMzE5LTBhNjU0ODAwOTY4ZCIsInMiOiIyYWMyN2YxYzc2IiwiYyI6InRhbmtiIn0=/attachments/0",
        "content-type": "text/csv",
        "name": "widget-order.csv",
        "size": 554
    }
]
```

An inbound email has one or more attachments accessible through authentication. For this purpose, the method below makes use of `GuzzleHttp\Client`.

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection;
use GuzzleHttp\Client;

class MailgunWidgetsController extends Controller
{
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        try
        {
            $attachs = request('attachments');

            if(!is_null($attachs)) {
                $attachments = json_decode($attachs, true);

                foreach($attachments as $k => $a) {
                    $httpClient = new Client();
                    $resp = $httpClient->request('GET', $a['url'], ['auth' => ['api' => 'key-example']]);
                    $imageData = $resp->getBody();
                    $base64 = base64_encode($imageData);
                    $this->saveTicketAttachment($base64, $a['name'], $ticket);
                }
            }
            return response()->json(['status' => 'ok']);
        }   
        catch(\Exception $e) 
        {
            return response()->json(['status' => 'ok']);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, the code block enters the `foreach`, the url of the attachment is given by `$a['url']` but the GET request fails. I think an exception of some kind has occurred but it does not get logged in the `laravel.log` file because the code execution stops at the GET request.

**Objective is to access this attachment and convert it to its base64 encode.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct implementation to generate a `base64 encoded` string from an inbound email attachment using `GuzzleHttp\Client` as:

```
private function getTicketAttachment($attachment)
{
    $httpClient = new Client();
    $response = $httpClient->get($attachment['url'], [
        'auth' => ['api', env("MAILGUN_SECRET")], 
    ]);
    $imageData = (string)$response->getBody();
    $base64 = base64_encode($imageData);
    return $base64;
}
```

Comment: could you please elaborate furthere how you succeded with saving the attached files to storage?

Answer (score 1):

I write this for others coming here following the [tutorial on laravel news](https://laravel-news.com/laravel-inbound-email)

this is how you grab the file and puts it in your storage folder:

```
Storage::put(.$file['name'], $response->getBody());
```